# How can I allow the user to select a video, then play the video in Android?

Tags: android

I have not been able to find how to let the user choose a video from their videos, then playback the video in the app.  How can I do this?

This is all the code I have for videos right now:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent( android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE );
startActivityForResult(intent);
```

I don't know how to access the file the user chooses.

Comment: and your code?, at least the part where you try to show the local files in devide

Comment: i posted all the code i have for videos.  I didn't do it before because it is barely anything

Answer (score 1):

1. For choosing video :

   ```
   private static final int PICK_FROM_FILE = 1;

   btn_browse_vid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
           i.setType("video/*");
           startActivityForResult(i, PICK_FROM_FILE);
       }
   });
   ```
2. xml for display video :

   ```
   <VideoView
     android:id="@+id/myVideo"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
   ```
3. onActivityResult :

   ```
   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
       return;

     Uri vidUri;
     if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE) {
       vidUri = data.getData();
     } 
     //set the video path
     VideoView vidView = (VideoView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
     vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);

     //media controller
     MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(YourActivity.this);
     vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
     vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);
   }
   ```